# Where this points in setState in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, reference, components, this

I am stuck at understanding the `this` keyword in the following code of React. I hope you guys can clear me. Please check my simple code of React  JS.

**Board Class render**

```
return( <Comment key={i} index={i}  >
                            {value}
                        </Comment>
```

in comment class

```
constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {editing:false}
    }

render(){
return(<div className="commentContainer">
                <p>{this.props.children}</p>
                <button onClick={this.edit} className="button-primary">Edit</button>
                <button onClick={this.remove} className="button-danger">Remove</button>
            </div>)
}

edit(){
alert('comment')
this.setState({editing:true});
}
```

1. I am calling `Comment` from `Board` component so in Comment render function `this` will refer to `Board` or `Comment` class?
2. If it is pointing to Board then on click of edit button it should show error that `edit()` function is not defined in `Board` class?
3. If it is pointing to `Comment` class (which is actually because when I clicked it gives alert) then under edit function I am using `this.setState` so it should update editing state which is not happening and giving error of "undefined setState"

and when I use

```
<button onClick={this.edit.bind(this)} className="button-primary">Edit</button>
```

it works which means it was not pointing to Comment that's why I need to bind it with Comment. Total confusion, I saw a video where simply this.setState working,

4. Also If its pointing to comment then how it gets value of this.props.children

Can anyone clear me please.

Answer (score 0):

The auto-binding of this in the `render()` function is not possible using React class syntax. If you use `React.createClass({})` instead of `class extends React` it will be automatic. If you prefers use classes, you can bind methods with `this` manually in the class constructor :

```
constructor() {
   super();
   this.edit = this.edit.bind(this);
}
```

You also can use new possibilities of es2016 syntax (with some transpiler configuration) and use fat arrow function as class instance property :

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   state = { editing: false };
   edit = () => { /* method content */ }
   render() {
      // ...
   }
}
```

See [this article](http://www.ian-thomas.net/autobinding-react-and-es6-classes/) for more informations.

Comment: yeah so why do we need to bind edit function why cant we simply call this.edit and under edit function this.setState

Comment: when I used this.edit under render() function it called edit function and alerted 'comment' but error is coming when I am using this.setState

Comment: Because if `edit` is not binded to `this` (= classe instance), it can't know `this.setState` method. @BhuvneshGupta `alert` doesn't needs context (`this`) to be fired.

Comment: can you please clear? because I saw this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qh3dYM6Keuw&index=4&list=PLoYCgNOIyGABj2GQSlDRjgvXtqfDxKm5b  at 3:31 seconds this.setState working perfect without any error

Comment: or just simple tell me under render() this is pointing to which class Board or Component?

Comment: @BhuvneshGupta render is pointing `Board`, you can execute `edit` which is part of `Board` instance

Comment: nooo? edit() function is defined in Comment class not in Board and when I am clicking on button its firing Comment's edit function

Comment: @BhuvneshGupta Sorry I meant `Comment` component obviously

Comment: so if it is of comment component so similarly it should trigger this.setState() because edit is in same class. Also did you check video shared in above comment? in that video you can see this.setState working without binding

Comment: That's not the same thing in your case that in the video, the call of this.setState is done from the render method. (it's a callback of setTimeout using arrow function, the context is preserved). When you pass a reference to a function into an attribute `onClick={this.edit}`, `this.edit` is executed by React which is not capable to de the binding by itself.